# missing XML start tag in theme.xml

Tags: magento2, xml, luma-theme

Normally a XML file always needs at least the following starting line:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

The `theme.xml` files in the official distribution lack this tag, see for example the `luma` theme's file here:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/theme.xml

Why does this work, and why is this implemented like this?